# How to align raggedright caption with it's figure

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, captions

This is what I have:

[image]

and this is what I need:

[image]

that is, a raggedright caption aligned with its (centered) figure. Some of my code is this:

```
\documentclass[11pt, openany]{book}

\renewcommand\sfdefault{cmss}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[top = 2cm, bottom = 1.5cm, left = 1.5cm, right = 1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float} 

\usepackage{caption}
% Para graficos 'side by side' usando Tikz. No es compatible con 'subfig'.\
\usepackage{subcaption} % es mejor que subfig
    %\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat = empty} % Descomentar si se quiere que NO tengan un formato los \caption (los \caption* safan)
    \captionsetup{labelfont = bf, 
                justification = raggedright, 
                singlelinecheck = false, 
                format = hang, 
                skip=0.333\baselineskip}%, labelformat = empty} % descomentar esto para cambiar el label de los \caption.
    \captionsetup[sub]{labelfont = up, justification = centering}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{}
    \includegraphics[width = 0.8\textwidth]{figure}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

The answer I'm looking for must contain the figure centered. Thanks you!

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose the image along with caption inside a `minipage` of reduced width. This will align caption and the image together.

Here's a snippet for the image:

```latex
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{0.6\linewidth}
    \caption{}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

[image]